# What are the benefits of using #define over creating a function?

Tags: c

Warning: Please bear with me that I'm rather novice and don't complete understand this code.

So in the code base here, https://github.com/huwan/mini-vtysh/blob/master/vtysh/vtysh.c, instead of just creating functions, they use "`DEFUNSH`" as sort of a substitute for functions. The definition of "`DEFUNSH`" is as below:

```
#define DEFUNSH(daemon, funcname, cmdname, cmdstr, helpstr) \
  int funcname (struct cmd_element *, struct vty *, int, char **); \
  struct cmd_element cmdname = \
  { \
    cmdstr, \
    funcname, \
    helpstr, \
    daemon \
  }; \
  int funcname \
  (struct cmd_element *self, struct vty *vty, int argc, char **argv)
```

I don't quite understand its benefit, and to me, it only makes it harder to read. What is the purpose of using `#define`?

Comment: changing the tag to `C` since you're referencing C code

Comment: Well, to begin with, it saves you a lot of text per each {structure,function} combination.

Comment: `#define` is a macro directive.  Understand macros, and you will understand `#define`.

Comment: Use `gcc -E` to see what happens once the macro is applied

Comment: What makes you think this code has any benefits to begin with, or that it was written by a decent programmer? The linked source file shows a complete absence of proper program design. Github is a garbage dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it's not an issue of style -- it's an issue of the different capabilities of functions and macros. A `#define`d macro is a simple textual replacement where this:

```
#define FOO(x, y) x + y
FOO(2, 3)
```

Is the *exact same code*, by the time the compiler sees it, as:

```
2 + 3
```

In C, structs and functions can't be defined dynamically. This particular macro defines a function with a given name, something that can't be done by a function in C.

In some other cases, macros vs functions is a matter of style, taste, and coding practice. For example, there are arguments to be made both for:

```
#define COMPUTE_IT(x, y, z) x * y * ( z - 1 )
```

And:

```
int compute_it(int x, int y, int z) {
  return x * y * (z - 1);
}
```

It all depends on context.

Answer (score 1):

The macro declares a function, defines a structure variable that is initialized (including a pointer to the function just declared) and then writes the opening of the function definition.  It saves the programmers from having to write a lot of 'boiler-plate' code — standardized and unexciting code.